# Is it possible to upgrade the RAM of Lenovo yoga 310-11|ap

Tags: ram

I just got a Lenovo yoga 310-11|ap. The ram is 4GB ddr3 and sometimes its very slow because due to the limited ram. Is it possible to upgrade the RAM to at least 8GB?

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best source of information is usually service manual, so:
Google -> "lenovo yoga 310 11 service manual" -> in my case first link:

https://usermanual.wiki/Lenovo/Yoga31011IapHmm201609.643576809.pdf

-> there's nothing about RAM replacement => sorry, it's impossible

Comment: Yup its impossible, because it's soldered. :(